# How do I get the IP Address of server in homegroup?

Tags: windows, networking, ip-address

I have a number of systems connected to a Windows computer that acts as a server in a Home Group. The problem is that if this local server turns off and on or restarts, its IP Address might change for that system.

How will the remain devices find out the new IP address of this server? I want to automate the entire process since I want to host software and there won't be any network administrators to help.

Comment: Why do you think this might be a problem? Normally servers are configured to use a fixed IP address.

Comment: Even in a localgroup?

Comment: Why not? It's very easy to set that up in your router.

Comment: problem is that i want to have a generalized method since I cannot configure the router manually for every system to which i distribute the software

Comment: If you are distributing the software to a third party then it is up to the Administrator who installs it to make sure his network is set up correctly. You cannot impose your rules on some other persons network.

Comment: i can't actually do that since there wont be any administrator for that

Comment: There is always an adminstrator on every network. If you think there isn't then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: 1. What OSes are in use, for both the server and clients? 2. Why can't your router handle the naming? Why are you fiddling with IP Addresses? 3. Why can't the "server" stay on? 4. Why can't the server keep a static IP address? 4. What have you researched about this problem already?

Comment: @CanadianLuke The server would be just a windows based pc that would be in a shop and the pc would be turned off once the shop is closed, the client devices would be again windows and ios, the problem is that i want to distribute the software and i cannot manually change the router settings for every device to which the software is distributed

Comment: @CanadianLuke all the processing is being done by the local server which  requires that the client devices must know the ip of the local server inorder to make requests

Comment: I repeat, point 4 (the first one, typo on the second): Why can't the server keep a static IP address?

Comment: @CanadianLuke I run a xampp server on the local server machine every time the system turns on and so at that time the ip address seems to change , I don't know much about networking that has been bugging me,. On my research i came across things like using DHCP server , configuring the routers

Comment: The simple answer? Don't use IP addresses.  This is why we have systems like Bonjour, DNS, and Workgroups and HomeGroups in the first place, so we can give computers sensible (non-changing) names that are not subject to the whims of a network that is trying to manage itself properly.  If your software is trying to distribute itself on a company network and has hard-coded IP addresses then you've already failed.

Comment: @Mokubai Please help me with how to solve this problem

Comment: I can't see what your problem is beyond needing to set up a static IP.  Either you need to set up your DHCP server to always give that machine the address you want, or you give it a static address as below.  The *right* way to go is to use the computer **NAME** rather than address.  I suggest you actually describe what this software is, how it works and why it can only work the way you are asking as no one here can understand why this is a problem.  IP addresses have *never* been seen as a valid way to assure that something is coming from a particular computer.

Comment: ok, the problem is that the there is software that needs to run on a computer, there are number of client devices and they need to make a ajax post request to this server. The software running on this server does all the processing and return the response back to the client. The issue is the server may be turned off at times and i want that on turning on the server the clients must be able to make request to this server. The software would be distributed to a number of networks and manual configuration is not feasible, I want a programmatic solution @Mokubai

Comment: So what's wrong with using network name resolution?  Your question seems to be hung up on an IP address problem and the edits don't clarify much.  Focus on what your actual problem is, not what solution you think might work.  Almost all corporate networks use computer names for servers because it leaves the network infrastructure able to change as the needs arise.  If this is a "how do I write my program to take account of this?" question then maybe [so] is better, but here I would suggest telling us what machines types (Windows, etc) and asking how to set up name servers within that network.

Comment: OK Its a windows system and how do i set up name server in that network. Please help @Mokubai

Comment: I would suggest you ask a new question telling us every last detail of your actual problem and include the details that you've given me, don't get hung up on what you think is the solution and be open to suggestions of new ways. See our [how to ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on **Start**, then **Control Panel**
2. Choose **Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center** (or just **Network and Sharing Center**)
3. Click **Change Adapter Settings** on the left
4. Find the network adapter (NIC) that you are currently connecting with. Right-click it and click **Properties** (requires Admin access)
5. Choose **Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)** and choose **Properties**
   [image]
6. Choose the option to **Use the following IP address:** and fill in the blanks for your network.
   [image]
7. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>, and close the next window. Verify you can access the Internet.

You will now have the IP Address *always* set to this address. Because it is getting set to whatever was found below, once your computers find the new address, it will remember it. Your router (more specifically, the DNS Service) will match the name with the IP Address, and HomeGroups are built to just know (using IPv6, usually).

## How do you find out what you can put here?

1. Click on **Start**, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the *Command Prompt*.
2. Type `ipconfig /all` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Check for the following items:

   ```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.xxx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.xxx
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.xxx
   ```

   Your screen will output different numbers. Keep the information handy, and put them into the dialog above.
4. Type `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit.